# Android Asynctask on PreExecute method not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to start a `ProgressDialog` when `onPreExecute()` is called but it is not working.

**Homeactivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //switch condtion...
    case R.id.buttontime :                
        new FlightListTask().execute("");
        break:  

}

public class FlightListTask extends AsyncTask<String,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    protected String onPreExecute(String temp) {
        progresdialoglistview=ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "", "Loading");
        Log.e("onPreExecutive","called"+progresdialoglistview);
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground( String... params ) {
        return flightlist;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> flightList) {
        // listview code....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chnge your `onPreExecute` method as:

```
  @Override
  protected  void onPreExecute()
  {
      progresdialoglistview=ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "","Loading");
      Log.e("onPreExecutive","called"+progresdialoglistview);

  }
```

[onPreExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) method don't take any parameter and have void return type . so also remove return from onPreExecute

Answer (score 4):

You didn't **overrided** `onPreExecute` but **overloaded** instead.

`onPreExecute` doesn't takes any params and do not return anything. Use this instead:

```
protected void onPreExecute()
```